# Combine LINQ results having most common attributes

Tags: linq, merge

I have a Linq query:

```
var result = (from m in hl7Messages
                    join d in _esprEFContextProvider.Context.HL7Diagnosis
                       on m.MessageControlID_Guid equals d.MessageControlID
                    join i in _esprEFContextProvider.Context.HL7Insurance
                       on m.MessageControlID_Guid equals i.MessageControlID
                    select new
                    {
                        patientName = m.PatientFirstname + " " + m.PatientMiddleName + " " + m.PatientLastname,
                        m.PatientAccountNumber,
                        i.PlanType,
                        m.AssignedPatientLocation,
                        d.DxDescription,
                        m.AdmitDate
                    }).ToList();
```

and this is the result:

{
patientName: "Mike Mikey",
patientAccountNumber: "111111111",
planType: "Medicare A",
assignedPatientLocation: "1st Floor",
dxDescription: "**Chest Pain**",
admitDate: "5/17/14 11:46 PM"
},
{
patientName: "Mike Mikey",
patientAccountNumber: "111111111",
planType: "Medicare A",
assignedPatientLocation: "1st Floor",
dxDescription: "**Heart Failure**",
admitDate: "5/17/14 11:46 PM"
}

i want this:

{
patientName: "Mike Mikey",
patientAccountNumber: "111111111",
planType: "Medicare A",
assignedPatientLocation: "1st Floor",
dxDescription: "**Heart Failure, Chest Pain**",
admitDate: "5/17/14 11:46 PM"
}

Can anyone please tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a grouping on the allPatients or result to create a List of Description per patients then you could join this to another LINQ query

```
   var patientAndDescriptionList = from p in allPatients
              group p.DxDescription by p.PatientAccountNumber into g
              select new { PatientAccountNumber = g.Key, DescriptionList = g.ToList() // note could flatten to String with String.Join(g.ToList(),",")
};
```

Comment: (please see my below post)
Thanks, i have tried using aggregate. Here are my steps:
- (1st object) create a full list of LINQ object (contain most common attributes)
- (2 object) create a another LINQ object, that has distinct Account Number only, set DxDescription to string.Empty)
- take list of distinct account number of 2nd object.
- foreach accountnumber in list above: 
     get patients that have same account number (2 Mike above):
     select their dxDescriptions
     use aggregate to Merge them together
     assign that aggregate to the 2nd object
     return 2nd object.